# Retornar valor MAIOR com condição

Tags: microsoft-excel

boa noite.

Tenho uma planilha em NUMBERS (programa de planilhas similar ao Excel), pois uso Mac e há anos estou acostumado com ele. Me atende bem embora saiba que exista Excel para Mac.

Meu problema é o seguinte:

Como retornar na célula amarela a PRIMEIRA data futura da coluna B depois da data de HOJE (representado ali na figura como 29/1/2019). Ou seja: Qual a primeira data futura depois da data de HOJE.

Não há como a coluna A estar em ordem crescente ou decrescente no projeto atual pois se trata de agendamento de nomes em ordem alfabética.

A fórmula precisa identificar a PRIMEIRA data futura com base no dia de HOJE.

Alguém tem a solução?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Este software Numbers tem funções semelhantes ao Excel? Se eu te der a resposta em Excel vai lhe ajudar?

Comment: Boa noite! Sim, perfeitamente. Todas as fórmulas do EXCEL estão no NUMBERS.

Comment: Você quer somar 1 dia às datas da primeira 2ª coluna ou somar 1 dia à data de hoje?

Answer (score 2):

Usei as fórmulas Índice, Corresp, Menor, Abs e Hoje, então certifique-se de encontrar as fórmulas correspondentes no seu programa.
O resultado para a minha planilha é

`=ÍNDICE(B2:B10;CORRESP(MENOR(ABS((HOJE()-B2:B10));1);ABS((HOJE()-B2:B10));0);1)`

Claro que ao invés de usar o `hoje()` na fórmula você pode fazer uma referência direta à célula `D2` no seu caso.

**Detalhe:** Está é uma fórmula matricial, então, quando acabar de digitar a mesma é preciso apertar <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> (pelo menos no Excel). Após essa combinação de teclas você verá que a fórmula foi envolvida por `{ }` o que representa uma matricial. Note o que estou dizendo no detalhe abaixo na barra de fórmulas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[Contribuiu Kiwirafael](http://www.planilhando.com.br/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&p=150521#p150521)